# Misleading `ValueError` on bad formatting in python 2.7

Tags: python, string-formatting

When I try the following wrong code:

```
not_float = [1, 2, 3]
"{:.6f}".format(not_float)
```

I get the following misleading `ValueError`:

```
ValueError: Unknown format code 'f' for object of type 'str'
```

It is misleading, since it might make me think `not_float` is a string. Same message occurs for other `non_float` types, such as `NoneType`, `tuple`, etc. **Do you have any idea why?** And: should I expect this error message no matter what the type of `non_float` is, as long as it does not provide some formatting method for `f`?

On the other hand, trying:

```
non_date = 3
"{:%Y}".format(non_date)
```

brings

```
ValueError: Invalid conversion specification
```

which is less informative but also less misleading.

Comment: See: http://bugs.python.org/issue13790

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `str.format()` method, and the `format()` function, call the `.__format__()` method of the objects that are being passed in, passing along everything after the `:` colon (`.6f` in this case).

The default `object.__format__()` implementation of that method is to call `str(self)` then apply `format()` on that result. This is implemented in C, but in Python that'd look like:

```
def __format__(self, fmt):
    return format(str(self), fmt)
```

It is this call that throws the exception. For a `list` object, for example:

```
>>> not_float.__format__('.6f')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: Unknown format code 'f' for object of type 'str'
```

because this is functionally the same as:

```
>>> format(str(not_float), '.6f')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: Unknown format code 'f' for object of type 'str'
```

Integers have a custom `.__format__` implementation instead; it does not use `str()` internally because there are integer-specific formatting options. It turns the value into a string differently. As a result, it throws a different exception because it doesn't recognize `%Y` as a valid formatting string.

The error message could certainly be improved; an [open Python bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue13790) discusses this issue. Because of changes in how all this works the problem is no longer an issue in Python 3.4 though; if the format string is empty `.__format__()` will no longer be called.

Comment: Wonderful answer. Do you know what brings the `ValueError: Invalid conversion specification` error in the seconds case?

Comment: @HansZauber: `(3).__format__('%Y')`, because the `int.__format__()` method doesn't recognize that format string.